# How to show parent product number on listing page in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to show the parent product number of variant products on the listing page.
But I have no idea how to do it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi. Please show what you already tried out. Stackoverflow isn’t a free coding service.

Comment: Sorry bro for that but I am new to shopware6 and Stackoverflow. I tried a lot but it did not work. I want to learn like you and @dneustadt , so can you please suggest some resources where can I learn? again sorry for this, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a subscriber for the listing result events.
- Fetch key value pairs from variant IDs to parent product number.
- Use the key value pairs to set an extension to the affected product objects.
- In your product box template print the content of the extension.

Service definition:

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Subscriber\CustomListingSubscriber">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Doctrine\DBAL\Connection"/>
</service>
```

Subscriber:

```php
class CustomListingSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private Connection $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingResultEvent::class => [
                ['handleListingResult', 0],
            ],
            ProductSearchResultEvent::class => [
                ['handleListingResult', 0],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function handleListingResult(ProductListingResultEvent $event): void
    {
        $ids = $event->getResult()->getEntities()->getIds();

        $sql = 'SELECT LOWER(HEX(p.id)), pp.product_number
                FROM product p
                INNER JOIN product pp ON pp.id = p.parent_id AND pp.version_id = :version
                WHERE p.id IN (:ids) AND p.version_id = :version';

        $mapping = $this->connection->fetchAllKeyValue(
            $sql,
            ['ids' => Uuid::fromHexToBytesList($ids), 'version' => Uuid::fromHexToBytes(Defaults::LIVE_VERSION)],
            ['ids' => Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY]
        );

        foreach ($mapping as $variantId => $parentProductNumber) {
            $product = $event->getResult()->getEntities()->get($variantId);

            if (!$product instanceof ProductEntity) {
                continue;
            }

            $extension = new TextStruct();
            $extension->setContent($parentProductNumber);
            $product->addExtension('parentProductNumber', $extension);
        }
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{{ product.extensions.parentProductNumber.content }}
```