# Shopware 6 Product comparison - export variants and load parent data

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a product comparison and am exporting product variants.
Now I would like to load the `productNumber` of the products parent and tried the following:

```
{{ product.parent.productNumber }}
```

I get the following error message:

> It is not possible to read the parent association directly. Please read the parents via a separate call over the repository

Is it somehow possible to read the parent by `product.parentId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Shopware will not allow you to add a `parent` association and read the product's parent this way. There are several ways to achieve what you need though.

1. You can use the answer provided by David and have a custom field for the parent product number.
2. You can plug into an appropriate event (be it `ProductPageLoadedEvent`, `ProductListingResultEvent`, `product.loaded`, something else, or a custom event altogether)
   In the subscriber you can simply do

```
$parentId = $product->getParentId();
$criteria = new Criteria([$parentId]);
$parent = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();
$product->addExtension('parent', $parent);
```

This may get tricky when you are listening to the `product.loaded` event because it will trigger another one, but you can, for example, add a custom state to the context to alleviate the issue.

In addition, if you're trying to load parent data for multiple products at the same time remember about batching the requests to the database (so as not to query the DB 50 times if you need 50 parents).

3. You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73376902/16020231)
4. You can also implement a Twig Extension, similar to `searchMedia`, which would enable you to search for a product (in this case parent by parentId) in the twig template.

Answer (score 1):

In some way the parent only exists as a means to allow the variants inherit one and the same value. The parent passing on its values as inheritance is also the reason why it should not be accessed directly.

The product number isn't an inheritable field, as every product needs a unique number. If you want the variants to access a value of the parent, you need to use an inheritable field. You could create a custom field for products. Then set the product number as its value on the parent. This way you all variants could access that value as custom fields are inherited:

```
{# The following would be inherited from the parent by default #}
{{ product.customFields.my_product_number_custom_field }}
```